# HTML5/Javascript + Web Services

Tags: design-patterns

If developing web applications using **ASP.NET MVC** or **Ruby on Rails** make the application use the **MVC design pattern**, then if I build my application using only **HTML5/Javascript + backend webservices** (like WCF rest), then which design pattern will my application follow?

Comment: I think that would be the Client-Server architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern web idea which you are talking about does not really have a specific name (it probably should). I generally try to use backbone.js or ExtJS or the like to do an MVC in the browser and treat the server as a data source that can have its own logic as well.

Don't worry so much about what it is called as much as how to write good code and make something that does the job.

Comment: It does have a name, it's called building a client/UI (or multiple clients) and consuming a webservice. In fact the html5/javascript is just a presentation layer in the MVC pattern, but with Asp.NET mvc (no idea about ruby) you have tools to easily export to xml,json, etc instead of html

Comment: I think rails does as well. As do most major web frameworks (yaws, yesod, symfony etc)

Answer (score 1):

I call that "web app" development or "fat client" where you are including all your GUI interactivity on the client-side and the server is only providing data. MVC is more akin to "Enterprise Web Applications" or as I call them "pretentious layers of software".